# What was the architecture/pattern that existed before SOA

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, architecture, soa

I understand SOA  (Service-oriented architecture), and its importance, and how useful it is. But, what was the architecture in place for large enterprise applications...before the SOA existed?

What was it called?

Is there any latest alternative for SOA (I'm sure no, at the best there may be newer flavours...but just wanted to ask this here.)

Comment: What made you curious to know about it ? I am curious to know.

Comment: This question doesn't really fit the SO format. You might try asking on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am no expert, but if memory serves (not that it no longer exists), [EDI - Electronic Data Interchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_data_interchange) is/was in place.

This is still in place *today* at some of the largest enterprises (mfg, retail, etc.). At work, the truth is some of our new SOA implementations actually support these core/legacy EDI implementations because they're tightly integrated with pre-existing back-end ERP applications. So we might be SOA to the outside, but internally, they feed into  EDI / ERP architecture.

Comment: -1: EDI was not a predecessor of SOA, and in fact, is still heavily used.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I **explicitly stated that in my answer** even stating that as an example related to my "other life". Prior to SOA what would you say was the integration method between partners? I'm curious to your input.

Comment: SOA is not an integration method. It's a software architecture.

Comment: @JohnSaunders My bad. Ok, so what was _"it"_ prior to SOA? I'm getting really curious, I can't come up with anything other than EDI (aside from old school passing of data files via email/ftp)...although this question was already correctly suggested be moved outside of SO...so perhaps we're digressing too much....

Comment: There was no "it" before SOA. Not really. No general architectural style for connecting components across an Enterprise. Maybe component-based architectures like COM or CORBA? Nothing that got any cross-platform traction.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Well, I'll respectfully disagree and move on...perhaps terminology is just in my way :) _"EDI can be formally defined as the transfer of structured data, by agreed message standards, from one computer system to another without human intervention."_

Comment: Please read the question again. The OP hasn't asked what the previous integration technology was. He asked what was "it" before SOA, presumably meaning, what technologies or architectures fulfilled the same roles then as SOA does now (to the extent that the roles were filled at all back then). EDI has a far narrower scope than SOA, so I don't see that it should be part of the comparison.